# How to calculate value of a binary representation using exponentiation?

Tags: exponentiation, binary

I am new to number theory and struggling to understand how to take a binary representation and use exponentiation to determine the value. For example, if 
the binary exponentiation is represented as follows, how do I work out the value by hand? The hint provided by in the question is to consider what $$2^{2}$$, or $$2^{3}$$ looks like.

$$x =(2^{12} \times 2^{20})−2^0$$

edit: I believe I've solved it as follows. Thanks for your help. [Proposed Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ndb9.png)

Comment: $2^{12}\times 2^{20}=2^{32}$.  If you go and subtract $2^0$ from that....  You should know that a number like $1000000$ when you subtract one away from it becomes a whole bunch of nines, in this case $1000000-1=999999$, something similar happens in binary.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question seems to me to be just ordinary rules for exponents. The answer is $2^{32} - 1$. If you are asking about something else please edit the question to clarify.